# Retrieving row names using While If Loop

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm trying to retrieve the row names based on a condition in a column of a data frame.  I need to use a While and If loop to accomplish this.  I borrowed some code from a similar question/answer but can't get it to work.  I want to return the rownames for all values in column mtcars$cyl that equal 4.  Here's what I have:

```
cyl_4 <- 0
i <- 0
while(i <= 32){
    i <- i+1
    if(rownames(mtcars)[mtcars$cyl == 4]
    cyl_4 <- mtcars[i,1]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This code clearly won't run.  Your if statement has an unmatched parentheses.  Please edit to reflect the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 3):

It's a weird question but I think this is what you want:

```
i = 0
while (i <= 8) {
      j = i
      if (j == 4) {
            print(paste("for", j, "cylinders"))
            print(rownames(subset(mtcars, subset = (cyl == j))))
      }
      i = i + 2
}
[1] "for 4 cylinders"
 [1] "Datsun 710"     "Merc 240D"      "Merc 230"       "Fiat 128"      
 [5] "Honda Civic"    "Toyota Corolla" "Toyota Corona"  "Fiat X1-9"     
 [9] "Porsche 914-2"  "Lotus Europa"   "Volvo 142E"
```

You actually could easily get the answer without the loops:

```
rownames(subset(mtcars, subset = (cyl == 4)))
 [1] "Datsun 710"     "Merc 240D"      "Merc 230"       "Fiat 128"      
 [5] "Honda Civic"    "Toyota Corolla" "Toyota Corona"  "Fiat X1-9"     
 [9] "Porsche 914-2"  "Lotus Europa"   "Volvo 142E"
```

It's weird because usually when you use the `while` loop, you would want the loop to run until a certain condition is met, but in your case, you want specifically `cyl = 4`.
If you want all cylinders to be printed out, you could change the `if(j == 4)` to `if(j == i)`.

Comment: You're right to suggest not using a loop (+1). I would recommend not using `subset()` though, just go straight for `[, ]` notation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I understand there are easier solutions, but the purpose of this question was to learn how to use while loops.  I wasn't finding much helpful guidance online.  This worked great.  I changed the print function and assigned the output to a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop. Just do

```
rownames(mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4,])
```